# How to design a Data Access Layer for a database table that may change in the future?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

**Introduction:**

I'm refactoring (pretty much rewriting) a legacy application in my current internship. The part that this question will be concerned about is the database it uses and the way they retrieve data from it.

The database structure is:

1. There's a table that has the main records. Let's say each record is a measurement. It has some info about the measured material and different measurement information.
2. There's a table view they use that has the same information columns, plus some extra columns that contains data calculated from the given measurements. And it also filters some of the data from the table.

So let's say we have the main table with columns:

```
Measurement ID
Measurement A
Measurement B
```

The view has something like this:

```
Measurement ID
Measurement A
Measurement B
Some extra data (for example Measurement A * Measurement B)
```

The guy that is leading the development only knows some SQL, so he likes adding new columns that is calculated by some columns in the main table for experimenting. And this is definitely a **need** at the moment.

**Requirements are:**

1. Different types of databases should be supported (like SQL Server, Oracle, and probably some others).
2. The frontend should be able to show the view, which means even though some main columns will always stay the same, there may be some new columns including newly calculated values.

**My question is:**

What kind of system should I use to accommodate the needs of this application? I wanted to use Entity Framework, but the fact that the view may have new columns in the future is I think a problem. As far as I understand, I should map my classes to the database before compiling.

The other thing that I'm considering is maybe using Entity Framework to get data from the main table and do the calculations and the filtering that is currently done in the table view directly in the frontend, and skip the view altogether. Which sounds fine, though I don't know if they will allow me to do that.

What would you do in my case? Please take into account that I have virtually no experience with databases and ORMs.

Comment: Does this also involve write operations to the main table?

Comment: @GertArnold, it involves write operations to the main table but the main table never changes. Only the table view is likely to change (and with change I mean there may be new columns, basic columns stay the same all the time).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that using Entity Framework will be a problem if the underlying DB schema is always changing. It will require you to update the EF model on your end every time to grab those new columns.

Ideally, all of your database access is hidden behind the interface to your DAL, so that your application doesn't need to know about which ORM is being used -- if any -- or which database it's connecting to.

I hate to say it, but given your requirements, an ORM might not make sense. You might want to go with something more generic without any strong-typing. You could just simply always return a DataTable to your application layer, and it could loop through the columns and values to display whatever is returned. If there are fields you know will never change, you could create a manual mapping for those fields only into your application object(s).

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look to [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) system that are a lot more flexible on the schema. Or have a look to document database like [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/). All these systems allow the schema to change dynamically. You need to check the Pro's and Con's to see if it can fill you requirements.

(This answer is a bit out of subject as it's about replacing the SQL server and not really creating a DAL, but other answers cover the subject well and I would like to propose another way that may help.)

Answer (score 0):

If your schema is unstable, then using Entity Framework as a beginner is going to be a headache. The assumption is that you can just refresh the design canvas periodically to let the tool handle database table changes. You can try that for a time to see when it becomes too much of a pain, but without any prior experience using ORMs or Entity Framework it may not be worth the effort.

I would probably use something like Rob Conery's Massive ORM (https://github.com/robconery/massive). It gives you more flexibility with the underlying database schema and is a very small library. I remember it being ~300 lines of code and very easy to use. It uses C# dynamics so you'll have to be using >= C# 4.0 and be comfortable with that one concept but IMO it's worth it for the low-overhead. A full-fledged ORM like Entity Framework or NHibernate is going to cost a lot of learning cycles.

You could, of course, just stick to ADO.NET DataTables. They're a bit ugly and verbose, but they'll do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Entity Framework - Database First if the DB is changing. Of course, you will have to regenerate your classes when you want to be able to access new columns, when the DB schema changes.

If you need to accomodate different database servers, then you should take a look into implementing a repository pattern and abstract all your data access that way.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment

> it involves write operations to the main table but the main table never changes

confirms what I was hoping for. It means you can use Entity Framework as the core of you application and a different route to display data.

Suppose that for display (of the view) you use a classic `DataTable` (because all common grids support them, contrary to displaying dynamic objects). I don't know how create/update/delete will be done, but saving changes will at some point involve mapping a `DataRow` to a `MainEntity` object. You can write one method for that like

```
MainEntity DataRowToEntity(DataRow row)
{
    var entity = new MainEntity();
    entity.PropertyA = row["PropertyA"];
    ....
}
```

The `MainEntity` can be attached to a context, its status changed to `Modified`, and saved.